# Jupyter Notebook can't launchy

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, launch

Please i've been trying to launch jupyter notebook, but i keep having the same problem. I've tried reinstalling anaconda but i still have the same problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yquMn.png)

I've tried reinstalling on a different directory but the problem persist.

Answer (score 0):

This might helpful.

1. Open anaconda prompt
2. open jupyter using command
   jupyter notebook
3. If any error. Then try to install jupyter notebook using
   conda install jupyter